# What is a good way to compare two data pre-processing methods e.g better predictions and/or narrower HPDs?

Tags: bayesian, uncertainty, data-preprocessing

Given one dataset and two different data pre-processing pipelines, does it make sense to say that one of the processing pipelines is better if, given a regression model, it subsequently leads to a higher predictive accuracy?

If we use a Bayesian model to estimate the parameter uncertainty, does it make sense to say that one is better because the regression coefficient HPDs are narrower? Doesn't the HPD depend on the magnitude of the estimated parameter e.g. the HPD might be narrower, but does this mean that the uncertainty is lower? couldn't it be because its magnitude is smaller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression models, in general, are dependent on the validity of underlying assumptions. Common issues center on the presence of outliers, normality departures and independent assumptions (uncorrected/modeled serial correlation).

To the extent that one of your data pre-processing pipelines is 'better' in satisfying underlying assumptions, this may incidentally lead to superior forecasts. As such, better forecasting ability would be my choice.

Some of the violations I mentioned could also comparatively be checked between your two data pre-processing pipelines (see this source on [regression related data quality](https://www.quality-control-plan.com/StatGuide/linreg_ass_viol.htm)).